# Type Conversion Errors in Android Studio

Tags: java

I'm having trouble converting the type of my two variables `editPaginas_livro` and `editAno_publicacao` which are **int** and my variable which is a Spinner `spinnerCategoria_livro` which is a **string**.

```
EditText editPaginas_livro, editAno_publicacao;
Spinner spinnerCategoria_livro;

editPaginas_livro = findViewById(R.id.editPaginas_livro);
editAno_publicacao = findViewById(R.id.editAno_publicacao);
spinnerCategoria_livro = findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategoria_livro);

String categoria_livro = spinnerCategoria_livro.getText().toString(); //error: cannot find symbol method getText()
int paginas_livro = editPaginas_livro.getText().toString(); //error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
int ano_publicacao = editAno_publicacao.getText().toString(); //error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int paginas_livro = Integer.parseInt(editPaginas_livro.getText().toString()); 
int ano_publicacao = Integer.parseInt(editAno_publicacao.getText().toString());
```

Also set atributtes to your edit texts in xml layout
android:inputType="number

Comment: ```editPaginas_livro``` and ```editAno_publicacao``` are of type int in my table in SQL, the error must start from there.

Comment: Thanks for your help.